# Hyphens are causing a blank result

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, filter, quicksand

I'm having issues with hyphens in my slugs from a tutorial I'm trying to go through...  http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/create-a-quicksand-portfolio-with-wordpress/ and I'm having a problem when my client uses hyphens in the category. The category is blank when the client puts in a hyphen for some reason. Otherwise everything else is working perfectly!

Has anyone else ran into this problem? I'm thinking its a js problem but am uncertain as I am not receiving any console errors at all. So I'm not for sure how to debug.

Comment: It looks as if others are having the same issue. here is a link. http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/create-a-quicksand-portfolio-with-wordpress/#comment-684932160

Comment: I do not know if it will help you , But I had some problems with similar JS scripts and non-english characters which I resolved by applying `htmlenteties()` on all produced links.

Comment: Something like this? $term_list .= '<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="'. $term->slug .'">' . htmlenteties($term->name) . '</a></li>';

Comment: Actually , now that I think of it (was a long time ago ) I think it was `rawurldecode()` and if my memory is not wrong, it was applied on the ID ( or class ) of the div. but you can try any of the related functions like `urldecode()` `urlencode()`, `htmlenteties()` etc  and try to apply it to any produced link one by one until you find the culprit. again, not sure the problem is the same , it´s just rings a bell..

Comment: if you can't get that to work, and need that type of filtering functionality, see another great tutorial that does the same thing here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/creating-a-filterable-portfolio-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

why not use `term_id` with any desired prefix: `$term->term_id`. In this case You will have unique identifier and less possibility to breake something.

final version could be:

`$term_list .= '<li><a  href="javascript:;" class="sort_by_term_'. $term->term_id .'">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';`

will produce something like this:

`<li><a  href="javascript:;" class="sort_by_term_1234568">some long name with more words</a></li>`

Info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by